67 / 5.000 WCF client with WS-SECURITY without knowing the service certificate
Para crear un cliente en .Net que mediante WCF que consumiera un servicio web que implementa WS-SECURTY creaba un CustomBinding al que le agregaba tres elementos:

AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement
TextMessageEncodingBindingElement
HttpsTransportBindingElement
Con este CustomBinding y un EndpointAddress instanciaba el cliente, y luego establecía los certificados del cliente y del servidor mediante el siguiente código (VB.NET):

MyClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = myCertificate MyClient.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = serverCertificate
El problema que tengo ahora es que necesito consumir los servicios que forman parte de una red con más de 90 puntos de enlace, cada uno con su certificado, por  lo cual conocer de antemano el certificado del servicio es imposible, o poco práctico. La falta de seguridad de este enfoque no sería un problema, porque los certificados utilizados por los servicios deben cumplir ciertas reglas y se validarían en el cliente, pero WCF siempre me arroja un error porque no he establecido el certifidado del servidor.
He intentado establecer el modo de validación del certificado del servidor en "None" mediante el siguiente código, pero no ha resultado:
MyClient.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None

También he intentado establecer un CustomCertificateValidator con el siguiente código, pero me sigue reclamando el certificado del servidor:
MyClient.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CustomCertificateValidator = New CustomCertificateValidator

He intentado también establecer cualquier certificado para el servidor y validar el certificado real en el CustomCertificateValidator, pero el certificado que recibo en el validador es el mismo certificado que configuré y no el certificado real que llega desde el servidor.
¿No hay manera de consumir con WCF un servicio web con WS-SECURTY sin conocer de antemano la clave pública del certifidado del servicio?
Gracias por sus respuestas.
